# How to get access to value in Groovy Map with only one top level element

Tags: groovy

I have the following Map structure in my Groovy code

```
def myMap =  [100:[ind1:'1', ind2:' ', subfields:[[a:'Jossehonanon, Ismael']]]]
```

Note: I do not know the key (100 in this case), but i now that there is only one element at the top level.

Is there a shorter, more readable (better?) way to get to the subfields property than the construct i currently use?

```
def subfields = myMap[myMap.keySet()[0]].subfields
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is:

```
myMap.find().value.subfields
```

Answer (score 1):

`myMap.values()[0].subfields`

or

`myMap.values().first().subfields`